# Get source code back from web service publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

Strange situation this is!

I accidentally deleted the project, neither I have project backup nor System restore is working (Because, no old restore points are available).

Now, what I have in hand is publish content of webservice.

**Is there any way to get source code back from publish content of a web service in .NET?**

Comment: Next time make sure you use some form of version/source control http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control

Comment: I think he will remember it for the rest of his life. As a suggestion, use [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the assemblies, you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to get the source of the the assemblies. With the disassembler you can extract it and save it.

You will lose comments, formatting and some other stuff, but the main part should be useful.

As a suggestion, use [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/) or some other Version Control system the next time.

Comment: +1. That pretty much sums it up. And then he should take the lesson and make backups. Heck, I just deleted 200gb of research data yesterday by accident.... in about 23 minutes they are restored from backup ;) Backups ARE needed.

Comment: If it is compiled in assembly, it can be decompiled using [JetBrains DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) as well. But, recently I had the same issue and I was thinking about how to get back the source code. After I have seen this link, I have noticed that webservice source code file resides in Bin folder after you have published web service... so you can read your source file there even with notepad... but you must take attention twice while doing some process with this kinda files.. Source Control or Backup is a must!